# I want to know how to extract an unknown value from a string in cmd (batch)

Tags: batch-file, time, cmd, substring

What i wanna really do is to extract the time offset (o:+/-00.2925132s)from
this W32tm time stripchart

```
    C:\Users\Dr.Inoka\Desktop>w32tm /stripchart /computer:lk.pool.ntp.org  /samples:5
    Tracking lk.pool.ntp.org [192.248.1.162:123].
    Collecting 5 samples.
    The current time is 10/31/2017 10:27:31 AM.
    10:27:43 d:+00.5776977s o:+00.2925413s  [                           |*                          ]
```

what I did is this:

```
    w32tm /stripchart /computer:lk.pool.ntp.org /samples:1| find "o:"  >"%temp%\temp.txt"
    set /p var= < "%temp%\temp.txt"
    set var2=%var:o=%
```

But gives this output:

```
    10:49:58 d:+00.0168794s :+00.0040119s  [                           *                           ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FOR /F` command to capture the output of a command. You can then use the TOKENS and DELIMS options to parse the output. The offset output is the third space delimited field.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%G IN ('w32tm /stripchart /computer:lk.pool.ntp.org  /samples:5') DO set offset=%%G
echo offset=%offset%
pause
```